Understanding PostgreSQL recovery and REDO
According to official explanation of recovery in PostgreSQL, it's done in the following manner:

Read pg_control
Get the latest checkpoint record
Get the REDO point
Start applying WALs to the server from the REDO point(not the latest checkpoint record)

My question is as follows: if we have flashed all the data from the REDO point until the latest checkpoint record while running the checkpoint, why do we need the WALs from REDO to the latest checkpoint record? It seems that all the data until the latest checkpoint record is already on the disk... But the algorithm starts from the REDO point... Could anyone please clarify this process? In my understanding, all the WALs from the REDO point to the latest checkpoint record are extra on the recovery step

You need to read this WAL Configuration. The first paragraph is as clear an explanation as is possible.


if we have flashed all the data from the REDO point until the latest checkpoint record while running the checkpoint,

Because you haven't.  Or at least, you don't know that you have.  A checkpoint only guarantees that data which was dirty at the start gets flushed by the end.  Data dirtied during the checkpoint (after it started, but before it ends) is not necessarily flushed during the checkpoint. It might not get flushed until the next one.
